# How to use MapBooleanAsBoolean in AWS Database Migration Service?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-dms

In latest release AWS DMS introduced MapBooleanAsBoolean connection parameter to allow keeping booleans as booleans when migrating from Postgres to Redshift. Unfortunately docs are very imprecise about how to use it. I tested adding it as extra connection parameter in both source and target endpoints and mapBooleanAsBoolean and migrateBooleanAsBoolean, but nothing worked for me. Has anyone been able to make it work?

Link to docs for reference:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_ReleaseNotes.html

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you found an answer for this, but adding the extra connection attribute to the source postgres endpoint:

```
mapBooleanAsBoolean=true;
```

Worked for me. My target was s3 parquet files though.

It can be done via the console.

[image: ECAs in console]